# Graphql and Relay scalability

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, relay

today I was reading some articles that explained what are graphql and relay and how they work together. After that I have a question for you. It's possible to scale graphql?

Answer (score 1):

This Facebook engineering blog post mentions GraphQL used in hundreds of billions of API calls per day.  So the answer is yes, it is scalable. https://code.facebook.com/posts/1691455094417024/graphql-a-data-query-language/